# Why did Ken react in a positive way in this scene?

Tags: barbie-2023

Riding on imaginary horses, Ken, along with his other Kens,
finds his house turned into a Barbie house

> Ken: Is it just my imagination, or did these Mojo Dojo
> Casa Houses **just get dreamier**?
>
> President: That's because they're Dreamhouses, mother (beep).

Essentially, Ken is commenting on the positive changes or
enhancements to the house, which now has Barbie’s aesthetics

Why did Ken react in a positive way in this scene?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ken is not not reacting in a positive way. The acting shows Ken to be confused and/or angry. He said the "dreamier" part because, well, they're now Dreamhouses and not Mojo Dojo Casa Houses anymore.

It's hard to provide proof or sources of that, though... But it should be clear if you watch the movie at around 1h 31m mark, where this scene happens.